# Excel Formula for Sigma Equation

Tags: excel-formula

[image]
How to create an excel formula for the above equation?

Eg. N = 10, P = 9.4

Thanks!

Comment: Several ways, including (but not limited to) using `SUMPRODUCT` to run an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following user defined function:

```
Public Function Zigma(N As Long, p As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Zigma = N
    For i = 1 To N - 1
        Zigma = Zigma - (i / N) ^ p
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

This allows you to avoid array formulas.

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as an excel formula:

```
=A1-SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, A1-1))/A1)^A2)
```

[image]

Comment: This formula works very well, however since I'm creating a calculation sheet with other formula in the same column, I need to reference the H result from cell A:3. Thanks!