# Is there a excel sheet function with LOOP calculation?

Tags: excel

I'm wondering if there is any excel sheet function with a LOOP calculation.

Example: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55

LIKE: LOOP_SUM(LOOP_NUMBER,0 + loop_number) = 55

PS 
1. i know that i can get the result of this specific example with some solutions, like (10*11)/2, but i have some difficult calculations to do with loop, that there is no way in mathematic to calculate it without the LOOP solution. 
2. i know that i can do it with VBA, my question is only to find a way with regular built-in functions.

Comment: How would you expect to use that formula?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(1:10))`

Comment: SUMPRODUCT uses loop? how will you calculate 1*2*3*4*5 ?

Comment: Sure is.  If I do `=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(1:10)^2)` it would sum: `1,4,9,25,...` and not return `55^2`

Comment: `how will you calculate 1*2*3*4*5 ?` that is a new question.

Comment: You can adapt Scott's technique to your expression.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242105/excel-formula-for-sigma-equation  for example.

Comment: @Jacob specifically,  see Scott's answer to that Q

Comment: Have a look at this answer, may give you another option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53315780/4961700